# Differentiate a function of three functions?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Hopefully a simple question! But not one I know how to approach.

I've got three functions:

$u = \frac{x^3}{4}$

$v = 3(u^2 + u^3)$

$w = \frac{1}{v^3}$

Now how do I go about finding $dw/dx$?

I know that if the functions were products of each other, I could use an extended version of the product rule for three products.

Is there an extended version of the power rule that I can use for three functions?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

Use the chain rule:$$\frac {dw}{dx} = \frac{dw}{dv} \cdot \frac{dv}{du} \cdot \frac{du}{dx}$$

Comment: Ah, I see! Can I keep on applying the chain rule "forever", as it were?

Comment: So to speak, yes.